# .NET Windows Forms Controls with Design support work on 4.0 Client Profile

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Consider the scenario:

You need a Windows Forms Control with design time support. This creates a dependency on the `System.Design` that is not present on 4.0 Client Profile, so you use the 4.0 Full Framework for the control assembly.

Then in a project that you want the use the control, it will require 4.0 Full Framework, even that the required functionality is just for design time.

But, then you can use a `TabControl` that has `Verbs` and a designer that probably extends `ParentControlDesigner` that puts a dependency of the control on 4.0 Full framework, but your project will compile fine with the 4.0 Client Profile.

[image: TabControl from Microsoft DotNet]

<sup>As an example, the `TabControl` has verbs and a designer, but runs fine on 4.0 Client Profile.</sup>

There's any way to tell the assembly will just use the reference at design time!? Being this not possible, simple put **any** project that uses **any** control (with a custom designer), the dependency on the Full 4.0 framework, but the "native" ones from .Net no?!

Is this affirmation true? Why?

<sup>*Using 4.5 that was only full framework is out of scope for this question*</sup>

Comment: There is exceedingly little point in trying to solve this problem.  The control designer is only ever used at design-time inside Visual Studio.  On a programmer's machine, he always has the full version of .NET installed.

Comment: @HansPassant no, the question is for the control theres no problem having the 4.0 Full framework, but to use the control on the *user machine* it still requires the Full framework.

Comment: No, there's nobody that looks at the attribute or instantiates the designer class.  So the jitter has no reason to ever load System.Design.dll.  A missing DLL that never gets loaded never generates an exception.

Comment: I'm talking at compile time, how you derive your designer class without `System.Design.dll`!? You need to target 4.0 Full framework, even if at the user machine it will not load that assembly. Anyway, @PatrickHofman answer is objective and solve the "problem". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you have for example the `Form` class, it is decorated with the `DesignerAttribute`, which is available in the client profile.

It's definition:

```
[Designer( "System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         , typeof(IRootDesigner)
         )
]
```

The `IRootDesigner` interface is available too in the client profile, so there is nothing actually referring to the full framework, only the `string` is referring to it, but it is not evaluated at compile time.

Hence, you don't need the full framework to use the `Form` class, but you do need it to access the designer. That will read the `string` and will try to load the assembly containing the designer, which indeed needs the full framework, which is always available on a Visual Studio installed system.

If you want to implement it yourself, you have to split the designer and control classes in different assemblies, referring to another version of the framework.